# A point in a matrix subdvided in x pieces, how to know which piece is the point?

Tags: matrices

Note: I am developing a algorithm for CUDA.
My question is: 
I have a matrix of size N*N, and I will subdivide it in N pieces, like the image:

[image: subdivided]

and given a random point, how can I know which one of the N pieces the point is?
I am assuming that N is power of 2 to make it easier, but since it is not a fixed number, I am having no idea how to...

Comment: For parallelizing something in CUDA, this is an awfully strange way to partition a matrix.  Why not break it up into $n$ rows, or $n$ columns, or $m \times n$ chunks?

Comment: I have some particularities in my algorithm that keeps me from doing that... It would be very more trouble change everything else than this..

Comment: Sure, I understand how that goes :/

Comment: This is very painful :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a very strange way to partition a matrix, however if it must be this way then I would let $(x,y)$ be the random point, determine the angle $\theta = atan2(y,x)$ that this point makes from the positive $x$ axis, and use that to determine which section it is in.  This is a natural way considering that your partitioning is defined by angles about the origin.

You've drawn your particular problem with the first region starting at $\frac{3 \pi}{4}$.  Following that, the solution for $n$ sections is as follows:

Start with calculating
$$\theta = \text{atan2}(x,y)$$
Then your answer is 
$$ \left\lceil \frac{\theta + \frac{\pi}{4}}{\frac{2 \pi}{n}} \right\rceil $$
This will give you the secion that your point is in with the first being $1$.  If you want to start with the first being $0$, then you use floor instead of cieling.

Comment: I understand and trying to get it, but how can I determine which section it would be? Since it can be any number (power of 2) subdivisions...

Comment: Sue, I'll update with a more precise answer.

Comment: Thank you. It worked just as loup blanc did too, I think is similar, but my doubt is: How you get to that solution? What was your thought? Sorry for bothering, and thanks!

Comment: No bother.  Yes, just by thinking about it.  It is really by knowing trigonometry and geometry.

Comment: but what part of trignonometry/geometry did you use?

Comment: My thought process went like this: He wants the angle from that line so he wants some trig function that accounts for $x$ and $y$.  Mentally went down the list and decided atan2 was the best.  Then, you want to create $n$ bins which means one bin every $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$ radians.  Finally, using $atan2(x,y)$, you have an additional offset of $pi/4$ from the $y$ axis.  That's how I got the second equation, but I used the ceiling function because you want the whole bin number and the first one is $1$.

Comment: Got it,thanks. It was very helpful

Comment: I have another doubt: What if the coordinates starts with (0,0) and y increases as going down, and x increases as going right (just as screen)? I have this question because I got it done considering (0,0) as the middle, as a cartesian plan, but Thats not exactly what I needed.

Comment: For what you're describing, you've just changed the trig and the offset.  I noticed you un-accepted my answer...  You're welcome for woo the help.

Comment: I miss clicked and didnt noticed it, sorry. But, using your idea, it doesnt work changing this, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be our random point and let $N=2^p$. We calculate the angle, in $[0,2\pi)$, $(Ox,OM)=\theta=\dfrac{2\pi}{N}\alpha$. We convert $\alpha\in[0,2^p)$ in a binary number $\alpha=\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_p\bullet\beta_1\cdots$. Then $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_p$ is the code of the considered piece.

EDIT 1: Since $N$ is finite, you must associate a piece to $M=(0,0)$.

EDIT 2: Assume $p=5$ and $\theta=7/3$ ; then $\alpha=2^5\theta/(2\pi)= 11.88356908\cdots\;(convert\; binary\rightarrow)\;1011.11\cdots$ and  $\alpha_1\cdots\alpha_5=01011$. We encode the $2^5=32$ pieces with binary numbers from $00000$ to $11111$ and $M$ is in the piece that is coded $01011$.

Comment: Sorry I didnt understand, why is it 2pi/N? and the part of binary number I didnt either. If you could explain me more, please.

Comment: I am wondering how you get there, what did you use, etc...

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I have another doubt: What if the coordinates starts with (0,0) and y increases as going down, and x increases as going right (just as a screen)? I have this question because I got it done considering (0,0) as the middle, as a cartesian plan, but Thats not exactly what I needed.